# Apache server on Ubuntu not working from remote location

Tags: apache2, django

I have a problem with Apache server on Ubuntu being blocked on port 80 when I try to access it from outside of my local network. On network server, I'm running Django application with mod_wsgi.

**Things that I already tried:**

- Contacted ISP if they are blocking port 80, which they don't.
- Disabled UFW.
- I tried to mess around with iptables, but I did not manage to make a progress:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:5800
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:30033
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:10011
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.4           udp dpt:9987

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I already have multiple port forwarded services running on server and they work just fine, I'm only experiencing this issue with Apache.

Comment: There isn't a lot to go on to help you solve this issue. When you say you disabled UFW, how did you do that?  Did you allow port 80 with it?  What command did you give it?  How is your port forwarding configured?  Can you provide the configuration or screenshots?  Can you access the site from other machines on your local network?

Comment: I disabled it using `sudo ufw disable`. I am configuring port forwarding via ISP's official cloud software. Yes, I am able to access the website from any macine on my local network. Internal and external ports are forwarded like this: 80-80. I hope this helps.

Comment: If you can access it from other machines on the local network, the problem is with the port forwarding.

Comment: Is it possible that there is a setting in Apache/Django that blocks traffic from outside, even if you have open ports?

Comment: Traffic from your router looks nearly identical to traffic from another machine on your network.  It would be possible to write a rule that blocks that traffic, but I wouldn't expect there to be such a rule in place unless you specifically implemented it.

Comment: Thank you so much for help, I guess I will check at my service provider again.

Comment: I figured it out, as @StephenOstermiller said, i had multiple ips binded on port 80. I deleted everything else and now works, thank you so much.

Comment: I’m closed this question because you indicate in the comments that you found a solution without getting any answers.  It looks like your problem was unrelated to what you actually posted. Leaving this up and getting it answered would be unlikely to help anybody else in the future.